# How do I make dashboard widgets active on logon?

Tags: macos, mac, dashboard

There are a few dashboard widget that are useful even when not going in Dashboard. For example, [SVN Notifier](http://lab.arc90.com/2008/04/02/svn-notifier/) sends a Growl notification when commits are made to a repository you want to watch. Or, [Delivery Status](http://junecloud.com/software/mac/delivery-status.html) does the same for status update on tracked packages.

The thing is when I log into OS X, those status updates won't happen until the first time I actually enter into Dashboard, so it looks like they are not initialized at startup. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dashboard KickStart](http://www.alwintroost.nl/?id=40)

Alternatively, save the following Applescript as an application and set it to open at login.

```
ignoring application responses
   tell application "Dashboard"
      launch
   end tell
   tell application "Expose"
      launch
      launch
   end tell
end ignoring
```